# Gradle - Add JavaFX SDK to classpath

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, javafx, classpath

I am using **gradle** in **Eclipse**, and my gradle.build is pretty basic (adds java plugin, sets repos and not alot more) and I am building a **JavaFX** program. All my code compiles and run correctly with my build scripts with 0 errors.

I am just annoyed at the fact when I add the JavaFX SDK to my build path libraries, I can see my project has it listed. When I sync my project with Gradle, gradle removes this SDK from my classpath file.

What do I need to add to my build script to stop this from happening and gradle to normally inject it into my .classpath as it does with anything else I add?

Cheers,

P.S. I'm really new to gradle and groovy and this is my first 'project' working with it. Apart from this one annoyance, it's been smooth going.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this issue: completely forgot classpath is todo witth eclipse and not java/gradle.

Adding:

```
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

eclipse {
    classpath.containers 'org.eclipse.fx.ide.jdt.core.JAVAFX_CONTAINER'
}
```

to my gradle.build file solved this issue.

I actually found a solution for this via https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/javafxports/Fn92C5ysC60 'android forum' while looking up how I could automate the building of eclipse.

Cheers if anyone looked into this.

---

As a side note, as I was confused about this first: A JavaFX project is no different from a Java project and you don't need to specify the fact you're using JavaFX to your ide to be able to execute JavaFX code. So I was confused why my IDE had a 'Start a new JavaFX project' and 'Start a new Gradle Project' but no JavaFX/Gradle project.

You don't 'need' a JavaFX plugin like my project originally had either.

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem, you need [JavaFX-Gradle-plugin](https://github.com/FibreFoX/javafx-gradle-plugin), it's a plugin that enable JavaFX support on Gradle project.

This is the link of plugin: https://github.com/FibreFoX/javafx-gradle-plugin, where you can find all infos and example...

All of you need is to start a new Gradle project, then add to your file build.gradle this code:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath group: 'de.dynamicfiles.projects.gradle.plugins', name: 'javafx-gradle-plugin', version: '8.8.2'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies{
    // put here your project dependencies
}

apply plugin: 'javafx-gradle-plugin'

// these values are the examples and defaults
// you won't need them all

// configure javafx-gradle-plugin
jfx {

    // minimal requirement for jfxJar-task
    mainClass = 'YOUR.MAIN.CLASS'

    // minimal requirement for jfxNative-task
    vendor = 'YOUR NAME OR COMPANY'

    // some optional task
    jfxAppOutputDir = 'build'
    jfxMainAppJarName = 'YOUR APPLICATION NAME.jar'
    manifestAttributes = [
        "Specification-Version": 1.0,
        "Implementation-Version": 1,
        "Built-By": "YOUR NAME OR COMPANY",
    ]
    // for a full list of available settings, look the class "JavaFXGradlePluginExtension" on plugin project
}
```

This is the only plugin that I've found for use JavaFX with Gradle.
I'm working with Eclipse on project with same problem, and I've solved it a few days ago.

Hope this help,

BoGnY

Comment: FYI, the author of this plugin has said that as of April 2018, the current version is being retired (he is not working on it anymore), and that he is privately working on a new one, with no definite expected release date. See github.com/FibreFoX/javafx-gradle-plugin/issues/119 for details.